# Android Webviews, saving the state when changing activity?

Tags: android

I have a number of different webviews, all in their own activity.

When a menu item is pressed a new activity loads and so does it's webview.

Now clicking between activities reloads each webview, is there a way so that when changing activities the web page doesn't reload and it remembers where the user was?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView method saveState()/restoreState() and save it to activity onRestore bundle and use saved value in onCreate method if the previous Activity will be destroyed.
You can use similar method which is described here (but used for only configuration change):
http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/